# Making Gantt Chart Column Labels More Readable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-gantt

[image]Description:
I'm currently working on a Gantt chart where the column labels have become unreadable due to the large number of columns. Although I've attempted to adjust the column width, it hasn't completely resolved the issue.

Details:

I've set the column width property, but it hasn't adequately addressed the readability problem.
The column labels currently display intervals for every minute, which is overwhelming and makes the chart difficult to interpret.
I'd like to change the column labels to display intervals of 15 minutes instead, which would improve readability without losing too much detail.
Question:
How can I modify the Gantt chart configuration or settings to change the column labels to display intervals of 15 minutes instead of every minute? Are there any specific options or parameters that I should adjust to achieve this?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

here my html code:

```html
<div class="col-sm-12"
     gantt data="ganttEventsData"
     from-date="ganttOptions.fromDate"
     to-date="ganttOptions.toDate"
     view-scale="ganttOptions.scale"
     headers="ganttOptions.headers"
     current-date="ganttOptions.currentDate"
     max-height="ganttOptions.maxHeight"
     side-width="ganttOptions.sideWidth"
     allow-side-resizing="ganttOptions.allowSideResizing"
     filter-row="filterByUserOrJobNameOrTaskNameOrJobId"
     expand-to-fit="ganttOptions.expandToFit"
     task-out-of-range="ganttOptions.taskOutOfRange"
     column-width="getColumnWidth()"
     api="registerApi">
    <gantt-tree header="'Name'|translate"></gantt-tree>
    <gantt-corner headers-labels="ganttOptions.corner.headersLabels"
                  headers-labels-templates="ganttOptions.corner.headersLabelsTemplates"></gantt-corner>
    <gantt-tooltips date-format="ganttOptions.dateFormat"
                    template-url="views/node-gantt/node-gantt/node_gantt_tooltip.html"></gantt-tooltips>
</div>
```